# How do I pass parameters to android Intent in new scheme on chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, iframe, android-intent

I have a web app calling a native app on android via an iframe intent which does not work in chrome 25 according to the following....

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

The intent was structured like the following....

app://Requesttype=Testing&Type=123&tn=0000000000

In the new intent:// scheme how would I go about passing the parameters listed after app:// to the native application?  I haven't been able to find an example.

Comment: there is clearly something missing in the doc, however the link to the source contains some explanation. apparently it's about https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/content/Intent.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base#6591 a type, a dot, the key, '=', the value, and a semi-colon (rather than a &)

Comment: @njzk2 it is in the docs, you have it in the Path section.

Answer (score 64):

With the new scheme, you can pass arguments as extras to the App, but you must encode the URI as follows:

```
<a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;S.myextra=mystring;end">Do Whatever</a>
```

This will pass an extra String called "myextra" with the value "mystring". Having a look at the [Android Code](https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/core/java/android/content/Intent.java?repo=platform--frameworks--base#6591) we can see how the extra parameters need to be coded. The "**S**" at the beginning of the "myextra" parameter defines it as a String. Other types can be:

```
String => 'S'
Boolean =>'B'
Byte => 'b'
Character => 'c'
Double => 'd'
Float => 'f'
Integer => 'i'
Long => 'l'
Short => 's'
```

For example, if we want to pass two extra parameters, an Integer and a String, we can do this:

```
<a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;S.name=Perico%20de%20los%20Palotes;i.age=35;end">Do Whatever</a>
```

Note that you'll need to url-encode all the parameters.

In your Android app, you'll need to accept those extras. In the "onCreate" event of your Activity:

```
Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null){
    String name = extras.getString("name");
    Integer age = extras.getInt("age");

    if (name!=null && age!=null)
    {
       //do whatever you have to
       //...
    }
}else{
     //no extras, get over it!!
}
```

And, of course, add the filter **android.intent.category.BROWSABLE** in your manifest as shown in [this link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents).

Comment: Thank you! This is the first good explanation I've seen for how to add the extras to the intent uri.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Some additional notes: you can just use `intent:#Intent;...;end`, no need for `whatever`. The activity needs to have `BROWSABLE` and `DEFAULT` categories in intent filter. `component=` is actually ignored, use `package=` to specify your package.

Comment: I found a fix check my answer above

Comment: Do you know what can i use for serializable extra?

Comment: How about the encoding? It seems like android intents sent from the webapp are encoded in `UTF-8`, so if I send japanse words like `買い物` it gets encoded into `%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%84%E7%89%A9`. How can I ensure I receive the same word without encoding and decoding it?

Answer (score 8):

For the scheme URL:

```
appname://RequestType/?Type=123&tn=0000000000
```

You would want to map to an intent URL of:

```
intent://RequestType/?Type=123&tn=0000000000#Intent;scheme=appname;package=com.example.appname;end
```

Comment: where is the link to the other types?

Comment: The types, in fact, don't matter here. I've updated my answer for correctness.

Comment: How do i refer to the play store if the app is not installed?

Comment: That should happen automatically

Comment: it happens only if i add "package=mypackagename" otherwise it doesnt, and i was missing that

Comment: Can I specify an alternate URL instead of the play store? So in case the app is not installed, I do not want to go to the play store but to a webpage.

Comment: I don't believe so. That would be nice and powerful.

Comment: you can now with this key S.browser_fallback_url= check out this link
https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/

Answer (score 5):

You can no longer use an iframe and custom protocol to open a native app.

You can however use the existing [intent:// syntax](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) to launch and intent and pass it data, it has the added benefit of taking the user to the Play store if it is not installed.

You either encode the data in the "path" part of the syntax as documented so you could have `intent://play/?a=1#Intent;......;end;` or you could encode it as an Extra.

Comment: i can't find the part relative to path syntax in the documentation. all details i found are in the source, around line 3720. where did you find a more detailed documentation?

Comment: it says "HOST/URI-path // Optional host", this is the place where the data is passed through.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as what was asked in the question (query parameters) - but the intent syntax is a little obscure.

Comment: The link in the answer is dead. I think this is the updated one: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 4):

Intents are not working after 4.4.4, So this is what i am doing for my app.

created custom scheme to launch my activity in the AndroidManifest.xml with the following intent filter

1)

```
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data android:scheme="<<YOUR UNIQUE SCHEME(I SUGGEST YOUR PACKAGE NAME)"/>
</intent-filter>
```

2)
Construct market url with fallback url which opens your app through custom scheme created above.

`market://details?id=<<your app package from AndroidManifest.xml>>&url=<<your app custom scheme from AndroidManifest.xml>>://yourdomain.com?encoded(p1=v1&p2=v2....etc)`

this opens the store if your app is not installed, and opens the app with the intent data if the app is already installed, with your decoded parameters.

Hope this helps