# Linking to facebook share from android browser

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

I'm trying to link to the Facebook android app from the browser but can't find the right scheme. I looked at the suggestion from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15597586/2170265) and I changed some stuff around. When I try it in the browser it always takes me to the Play Store for Facebook and not the actual app, even though I have it installed. Also, when I try running the samples from the above post, they take me right to the QR scanner.

Here is my best attempt:

```
<a href="intent://fb/#Intent;package=com.facebook.katana;end">test me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out I needed to edit the scheme to get to the app. Apparently, this works:

```
<a href="intent://fb/#Intent;scheme=fb;package=com.facebook.katana;end">test me</a>
```

I guess my next question would be how can I bring up the publish screen so a user can share to their profile.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How do I pass parameters to android Intent in new scheme on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome) it was possible to share a profile by adding an extra user id parameter like this:

```
<a href="intent://fb/#Intent;scheme=fb;package=com.facebook.katana;l.extra_user_id=100001529066447;end">Launch Facebook</a>
```

Unfortunately Facebook confirmed that this is not possible anymore since a security exception: [Security exception when opening ProfileTabHostActivity through intent](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/286768364773190?browse=search_508ceda838bb38b23277350)