# Pass referrer data through chrome intent to google play

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, intentfilter, referrals

So I have a mobile web that would try to open my android app, if it does not exist, it would fall back to google play.

for chrome, i use this intent:

```
intent://some_data_sent_to_app#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=package_name;end
```

and it works fine,
now I want to send some referrer string to google play for the INSTALL_REFERRER in an app.

I tried the following link, it has no problem of sending data to google play, but it would not try to open the app

`intent://some_data_sent_to_app#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=package_name&referrer=referrer_string;end`

I wonder what is the correct way to open the app and fall back to google play with the referrer data being passed?

Comment: did you find the solution? I am looking for the same.

Comment: I posted the same issue on chromium as well, hopefully they will reply soon, here is the link: [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=395712)

Comment: I also have been trying to get this to work.  I found the following article showing how to add extras to the intent

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome

"<a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;S.name=Perico%20de%20los%20Palotes;I.age=35;end">Do Whatever</a>"


I unfortunately don't have a way to test if it adds the params to the google play URL

Comment: They closed that issue posted at Aug and merged it in the newer issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459711 (it has "Unconfirmed" status for now...)

Comment: Ya, since they have no response, so i opened a new thread to poke them again =D

Comment: What about more cross-browser solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25374575/1298357

Comment: try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it can be done by passing `S.market_referrer=referrer_string`

For example

```
intent://some_data_sent_to_app#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=package_name;S.market_referrer=referrer_string;end
```

I have not tested this, but there are some check-ins in the chromium repo for this, don't know if it is available in the current version of chrome.

https://codereview.chromium.org/2061493002

Comment: According to [the comment from dev member](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459711#c35), “This change will be released in M53”, which will be [released on Sep 6th, 2016](https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar).

Comment: @praveen-yadav, Yes perfect it works, at least on Android 6.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that I am working with the team to get fixed.  Someone in the past suggested that you can use `intent://some_data_sent_to_app#Intent;scheme=app_scheme;package=package_name&referrer=referrer_string;end` however the logic of this has never worked specifically because the Chrome browser (and Android Browser) look for a package id that is direct copy of the string which is parsed as `package_name&referrer=referrer_string`.

Comment: Hi @Kinlan's You could fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With the new scheme, you can pass arguments as extras to the App, but you must encode the URI as follow:

```
<a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;S.myextra=mystring;end">Do Whatever</a>
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome)