# Clicking on the web link app will open

Tags: java, android, uri, deep-linking

I am trying to build an application where if I click the link my app(if installed) will open.But it's not working,don't know why.It's always redirecting to google.com

My manifest file

```
<activity   android:name=".DeeplinkingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://example.com/soham" -->
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/soham" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/soham" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

My test.html

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=http;package=soham.com.deeplinking;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com;end"></a>
```

I think the problem is in the html file.Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is incorrect, you are using the host of the [Android Intents with Chrome example](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents#example). You need to use the `host` and `pathPrefix` configured in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Your `host` is `example.com` and your `pathPrefix` is `/soham`, the link will become:

```
<a href="intent://example.com/soham#Intent;scheme=http;package=soham.com.deeplinking;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com;end">Deeplink</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.It's working now.Can you tell me about how to send parameters through the link.Suppose I have to send id =1,2.

Comment: You're welcome. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21304773/2837959) explains in detail how to pass arguments as extras to the App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This is working for my app:

NOTE: write below code within your launcher activity tag

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://WRITE YOUR HOST NAME” -->
            <data
                android:host="index.html"
                android:scheme="WRITE YOUR HOST NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://example.com/WRITE YOUR HOST NAME” -->
            <data
                android:host="WRITE YOUR HOST NAME.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/index.html"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="WRITE YOUR HOST NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is sample app,not in the playstore,don't have any website.So what should be the android:scheme and android:host