# Android Intent, send parameters?

Tags: android, url, android-intent, parameters, send

So, I've been checking a couple of posts related to opening apps from the browser but my question is.

If I want to open the app but I also want to send a string in the link (the string will containt some passcode to open a certain part of the app that needs to load some specific information depending on the string I send)

How to achieve this? So far I can open the app and also have a fallback url if the app is not installed. Where can I put the parameter I'm trying to send?

In the example it opens the app, but how can I send say, a variable code="112233code"?

Take a QR code

Thanks!

Comment: "If I want to open the app" -- is this your app that you are opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a question that might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome)!

I don't know how you open your app from the browser, but if you are using an intent like this:

```
 <a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;end">Do Whatever</a>
```

Then you can enconde your parameter like this:

```
 <a href="intent://whatever/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.what.ever.myapp;S.mycode=112233code;end">Do Whatever</a>
```

This will pass an extra String called "mycode" with the value "112233code".

In your Android app, you can recover those extras in the onCreate method in the following way:

```
Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null){
    String mycode= extras.getString("mycode");
}
```