# Passing values from webpage to Android activity

Tags: android-activity

I have learnt how to open an android app from a webpage  by making the HTML elements href like:

"  Take a QR code "

But I have used webpages that not only opens up the app, but also passes some value to a specific field in the apps activity.
Eg: a web page that has a button, such that when clicked, opens up the compose mail activity in the Gmail app and  fills the "to" input field with a specific email address.
Can  this be implemented? How can I go about this .Thanks in advance. 
        Pardon me if I haven't asked this question properly.

Comment: Please, can you detail the technique you used to open your app from a QRCode? We can try to help you from that.

Comment: <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>

Comment: I added it but its not showing up

Comment: Have you checked the following link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738276/how-do-i-pass-parameters-to-android-intent-in-new-scheme-on-chrome

Comment: Does this mean I need to have access to the apps program files to append this changes

Comment: It means that you can pass parameters to your apps. It's up to you to treat these parameters in your own app source code.